# stacked bar chart legend issue jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am facing an issue with the jqplot stacked bar chart legend
,
i want to do the placement of the legend in my own custom manner.
But whatever changes i apply doesnt take effect.

what i want
is this

[image]

but what i am getting in the legend is as follows

[image]

Code snippet i am using

```
var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
  var s2 = [7, 5, 3, 4];
  var s3 = [14, 9, 3, 8];
  var s4 = [14, 9, 3, 8];
  plot3 = $.jqplot('graph_stacked', [s1, s2, s3,s4], {
    // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
    stackSeries: true,
    captureRightClick: true,
    seriesDefaults:{
      renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
          // Put a 30 pixel margin between bars.
          barMargin: 35,
          // Highlight bars when mouse button pressed.
          // Disables default highlighting on mouse over.
          highlightMouseDown: true  
      },
      pointLabels: {show: true}
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
          renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
      },
      yaxis: {
        // Don't pad out the bottom of the data range.  By default,
        // axes scaled as if data extended 10% above and below the
        // actual range to prevent data points right on grid boundaries.
        // Don't want to do that here.
        padMin: 0
      }
    },


    legend:{
            show:true, 
            placement:'outside',
            rendererOptions: {
                numberRows: 2,
                numberColumns: 2

            }, 
            location:'s',
            marginTop: '1px',
            border:'none'

        }          
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set the renderer for legend.
Set `renderer` to `$.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer`

So the legend object would look like this:

```
legend:{
    renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
    show:true, 
    placement:'outside',
    rendererOptions: {
        numberRows: 2,
        numberColumns: 2
    }, 
    location:'s',
    marginTop: '40px',
    border:'none'
}
```

IMP: Also make sure, you have included the `jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.min.js` and `jquery.jqplot.min.css` files in the `script` and link tag(s) respectively.

You can check the working fiddle here: [Stacked Bar Chart with Legends](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/dy33ea54/)

Would like you to check the **External Resources** section on the left pane after you visit the above link. You can check the included JS and CSS files there.

Hope it helps. :-)

Comment: thanks @Anish Nair , need a little more help, how can i reduce the height of the canvas which renders the bars? i.e the height of the bars

Comment: @ViVekH If you are referring to a smaller chart, then set the height of the div(in your case `graph_stacked`) to a smaller value using CSS.

Comment: can you tell me how to remove the creamish color which is the background of the canvas on which the chart is getting rendered? also how to change the font size of the legend ?

Comment: Use this code : `grid: {
        background: 'transparent' //or use '#FFFFFF' (white)
    }`

You can also check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/dy33ea54/2/